# Program crash in x64, works fine in Win32

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, winapi, 64-bit

I'm working on an application which builds and runs fine in Win32.  However, in x64, it builds but crashes on run.  Looking at the code and narrowing down the problem, if I comment out the call to the below function, it runs with no problem.

```
void vec3_copy (double* v1, const double* v2) {
    v1[0] = v2[0]; v1[1] = v2[1]; v1[2] = v2[2];
}
```

I'm building in Visual Studio 2008 with the C/C++ compiler.  All updates have been installed.  Any ideas?

EDIT 1 (to answer comments):

The pointers should be valid, as in Win32, it runs fine.  No code is change and a different path is not taken, unless the pointer are somewhat modified because its x64 (will look into this).

Unfortunately, there is no information about the crash.  In Windows 7, it simply saying that it is looking for a solution to the problem, finds nothing, and returns in the command prompt.  In the event viewer, I was able to find the following information:

```
Faulting application name: DRR_C.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4b7a1ee1
Faulting module name: DRR_C.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4b7a1ee1
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000003950
Faulting process id: 0x16a4
Faulting application start time: 0x01caaec078a9c84a
Faulting application path: D:\Development\gpu\dev\DRR_C\x64\Debug\DRR_C.exe
Faulting module path: D:\Development\gpu\dev\DRR_C\x64\Debug\DRR_C.exe
```

EDIT 2 (to answer more comments):

Modified the line to,

```
memcpy(v1, v2, 3 * sizeof(double));
```

New error info has the same exception code and fault offset.

Comment: What kind of crash?  That code looks ok, as long as you're sure `v1` & `v2` are valid pointers...

Comment: That code is fine.  Your problem is somewhere in the chain of calls that leads to `v1` and `v2` having the particular values that they have in the call that fails (most likely in some pointer arithmetic that implicitly assumes 32 bit pointer differences or something similar).  That aside, you should really just use `memcpy( )` for this sort of thing.

Comment: Could this be allocated not using the double as the type. ie malloc(sizeof(MACRO) * 3) where macro is correctly defined for 32 bit and not for 64.   Aslo use memcpy

Comment: The exception code 0xc0000005 is for Access Violation Exception, which means your program is trying to read from or write to memory it doesn't own.  Can you run your application under the debugger and ensure the values of v1 and v2 are sane?

Comment: "The pointers should be valid, as in Win32, it runs fine." Non sequitur.  If you're somehow invoking undefined behavior (such as by dereferencing bad pointers), all bets are off.  It easily could run fine in one case but not the other. (I do agree that it's likely that you're truncating an address somewhere, though.)

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio 2008 you should be able to get a nice stack trace when it crashes that will show you the pointers being passed in. You'll notice that those pointers are not good, and looking further up the stack trace will likely show you where they're going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that it still crashes with `memcpy` confirms that the source of the bad pointer is elsewhere, as expected.

How big is the application?  It looks like somewhere along the line, a pointer was truncated to 32 bits or otherwise corrupted.  Most likely you will need to spend some quality time with the debugger to track down the exact location.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing which comes to mind and might have caused this crash is a conversion from pointer to int and then back. On Win32 both pointer and int are 32-bits long, on Win64 pointer is likely to be 64-bits long and int is probably only 32-bits long.